# Sinon useFakeTimers mocking delay promise times out

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocking, sinon

I implemented a non-blocking delay using `Promise` and `setTimeout` as follows:

```
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200))
```

I have a function which calls this delay:

```
const fn1 = async (v) => {
  console.log(v)
}

const fn2 = async () => {
  await fn1(1111111)

  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200))

  await fn1(2222222)
}
```

I then tried to use `useFakeTimers` from `Sinon` to mock the delay in a unit test (`Mocha`):

```
const sinon = require('sinon')

describe('Test 1', () => {
  it('Test 1.1', async () => {
    const sb = sinon.createSandbox()

    sb.useFakeTimers()

    await fn2()

    sb.clock.tick(500)

    expect(1).to.equal(1)

    sb.clock.restore()
  })
})
```

I expected `sb.clock.tick(500)` to mock time passing for 500ms such that the delay promise (`await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200))`) would resolve, `2222222` would be printed, and the test would pass.

However, I got the following error:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I'm not sure if my understanding of `useFakeTimers` is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the correct solution for this issue is to use `clock.tickAsync`.
I updated the target function a little bit for it to be more testable:

```
const fn = async (callback) => {
  await callback(1111111)

  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200))

  await callback(2222222)
}
```

And the working test is as follows:

```
describe('Test 1', () => {
  let sb

  beforeEach(() => {
    sb = sinon.createSandbox()

    sb.useFakeTimers()
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    sb.clock.restore()
  })

  it('Test 1.1', async () => {
    const callbackSpy = sinon.spy()

    fn(callbackSpy)

    expect(callbackSpy.callCount).to.equal(1)

    await sb.clock.tickAsync(210)

    expect(callbackSpy.callCount).to.equal(2)
    expect(callbackSpy.calledWith(1111111)).to.equal(true)
    expect(callbackSpy.calledWith(2222222)).to.equal(true)
  })
})
```

And problem is that `clock.tickAsync` is only available in later versions of `sinon`.
For some earlier versions (e.g. `2.4`), `clock.tickAsync` doesn't exist and I haven't figured out how to test the case above.